# What is the usual response time for an SO ticket?

Tags: support

I recently had trouble with my previous SO account and I submitted a ticket on Friday, 15 February, 2019. The issue is the following: I have accidentally removed all my logins in my previous SO account (**which I recall isn't possible as SO will usually show a pop-up saying 'You can't remove your only login'**). However, somehow, it did! Now I can no longer login to said account. Oddly, said account is still there: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9060223/richard-w

Naturally, I want access to said account back if possible. However, I have only received an automatic response from SO. Could someone please help me with this? Is the only way to wait for SO to respond?

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for the information. The issue was resolved on 21st of February 2019, with my two accounts being merged as the solution. Also, thank you support for processing my request.

Comment: There isn't really a "usual". The goal is 2-3 business days, but all of these emails are handled by real human beings, and there are only a small number of them. They may not work weekends, and Monday was a holiday in the United States where most of the team is based.

Comment: @CodyGray I see. Is that specific Monday a national holiday thing or is every Monday in US a non-working day?

Comment: It's [a specific national holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington%27s_Birthday). Not every company observes it, but the federal government does, and many companies provide their employees time off. I'm not sure if Stack Exchange did or not.

Comment: @RichardW "is every Monday in US a non-working day?" I wish :)

Comment: Related: [Declined request on MSE to implement an "estimated response wait time" indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317467/add-an-estimated-response-wait-time-to-the-contact-page)

Comment: I feel like MSO has let me down. I came here to see [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190736/271431).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can submit a follow-up request if you want, but someone should take care of it shortly. While I don't want to go too much into it, folks in the NYC office are dealing with a lot of emotional grief right now, and the weekend passed. So, they're a *little* backed up right now.

Your scenario also might need to be seen by a dev prior to them replying with guidance, so .. give it a little more time. Feel free to follow up if you wish, but it shouldn't take much longer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that something happened in NYC. Let me know if theres anything we as a community can do.

Comment: What happened in New York?

Comment: @gparyani I'm pretty sure Tim said they *"don't want to go too much into it"* right now, let's respect that.